# How to get Number of bands from a Bitmap in Android Device?

Tags: android, bufferedimage, android-bitmap, boofcv

I am doing an Image Processing algorithm using BoofCV in Android Client. For this, I did a demo on the server side using `BufferedImage`.

For that, my code was:

```
int numBands = bufferedImage.getRaster().getNumBands()
```

Now, I need to get the number of bands from a Bitmap Image.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, there is no concept directly equal to "bands" in Android `Bitmap`s.

You can look at the [`Bitmap.Config`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) to get some idea of the pixel layout and how colors are stored. I believe `ARGB_8888` is the most common one.